# Error Deploying AWS ECS: Dial TCP: No such Host

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc, amazon-ecr

I am attempting to deploy an ECS task / service, which reads from a private ECR repository. I have a public subnet, I enable a public IP in the service definition, and am using the out-of-the box ecsTaskExecutionRole. However, I continually get the following error:

```
Task stopped at: 2023-08-05T21:25:48.043Z
CannotPullContainerError: pull image manifest has been retried 5 time(s): failed to resolve ref 613431292675.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/model-service-repo:latest: failed to do request: Head "https://613431292675.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/model-service-repo/manifests/latest": dial tcp: lookup 613431292675.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com on 172.31.0.2:53: no such host
```

Here is what the subnet configuration route table looks like:
[image: subnet-with-public-access]

I have also added two ecr endpoints to my VPC:
[image: ecr-endpoints]

Anyone have any idea on what might be causing this?